# error: cannot open source file of some headers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pthreads, parallel-processing

i am trying to run  a phtread program in visual studio 2010.

in this code there is "sys/times.h", " sys/time.h" and file unistd.h.

i face errors which listed as follow :

- canot open source file sys/times.h
- canot open source file sys/time.h
- canot open source file unistd.h

can any body tell me is it possible to use this include file in windows visual studio??? if yes where can i find them???if not and they cant be used in windows visual studio what is the equivalent of this headers?????

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of pthreads for Windows (Google for pthread-win32), but it looks like your program is written for a POSIX operating system rather than for Windows.

Your best bet is downloading Cygwin and compiling it there.